# Is there a way in Lotus Notes Formula to check if a view is empty?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

In the starting form of our database we created a table which includes a view that shows relevant information. Of course sometimes there is no relevant information, so sometimes the view is empty. If this is the case we want to hide the table and therefore the view.

The problem now is, I can't find a way to check if a view is empty, only using the Formula Language. I think I could do it in Lotus Script but that I can't use for hiding the field. So is there a way to check if a view is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use @DBColumn in the hideWhen:

```
_lkp := @DBColumn( "" : "NoCache" ; @DBName ; "NameOfView" ; 1 );
_res := @If( @IsError( _lkp ) ; "" ; _lkp );
! (_res != "")
```

This Formula will return the contents of the first column in your view. If their is no content an error or empty value will be returned.

The double negation is necessary, if "" could be a valid value in that column, then the return value could look like

`"value1" : "" : "value3"`

and the comparison `_res = ""` would return True, because there is ONE blank value...

Comment: It would be a good idea to make execution of the DbColumn conditional on @IsNewDoc in order to avoid the overhead of re-executing a NoCache lookup any time the form is refreshed.

Comment: Wouldn't that also return True if the @DbColumn tried to return more than 64Kb of data?

Comment: No, normally not. In fact dbcolumn CAN return more than 64kb data. Your formula will only throw an error, if you try to save that return value somehow or try to use it in another @Function...